# how I can return some data from cake shell?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I wrote some cake php shell and I need some data as a result of executing it - let's say some data in json - is it possible to return some data from cake shell command? Or maybe there is some workaround? The problem is that this shell will be executed by some external script (not cake) and my shell should return some data...

Comment: you could also write to a file and return the filename (or use a fixed filename). then your external script could grab the file content afterwards

Comment: The problem is that many external scripts will execute this shell in parallel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Shell::out()](http://api.cakephp.org/class/shell#method-Shellout) function to send output to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

from cake shell you can simply run GET request with parameters to some address where you can listen for it...